# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ly (flex and bison, Ubuntu 20.04.2)

Tags: apt, 20.04, compiling, gcc, bison

I just switched from Windows10 to Ubuntu 20.04.2, and after installing Flex and Bison using these commands :
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get flex bison`

I get an error after running `gcc lex.yy.c syntaxique.tab.c -lfl -ly -o acad`
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1MLL.png)

Please

- How can I get all the appropriate development packages for flex and bison installed ?
- Do I have to copy libraries to the bin folder like in windows?
- If gcc works, how i compile the program.txt? is it with `acad<pgm.txt` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `libfl` and `liby` appear to be provided by the `libfl-dev` and `libbison-dev` packages respectively - not by the `flex` and `bison` packages

Comment: @steeldriver It worked after installing libbison-dev! but please how to compile the txt program? 'exeFile<pgm.txt' doesn't seem to work. Thanks a lot